# How to make parentheses under math formulae?

Tags: math-mode

How to make parentheses (with labels J1 and J2) as shown on the picture below?

[image: Example of parentheses under math formulae]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\underbrace`:

```
a = \underbrace{a + b}_{=c}
```

creates

[image]

Additionally, as stated in the comments, put the whole thing in braces to get the spacing before and after right:

```
a = x + {\underbrace{a + b}_{=c}}
```

Comment: +1. Hint: Enclose the entire underbrace expression in curly braces -- like `{\underbrace{a + b}_{=c}}` -- so that it'll be treated as a math-ord rather than as a math-op object. (This is relevant for the spacing before and after the underbrace expression.

Comment: +1 for this comment. Although the question was so basic, the terms math-ord and math-op are probably not understood... ;)